# What does the OpenGL command suffix 'v' represent?

Tags: opengl

Generally, OpenGL commands has a suffix like 'i', 'f', 'v', etc. I know it's specifying the parameter type.

```
void glGetBooleanv(GLenum pname, GLboolean *params);
```

Why is 'v' used for a pointer and what word does it represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the standard:

> A final `v` character, if present, indicates that the command takes a pointer to an array (a **vector**) of values rather than a series of individual arguments
>
> – *[OpenGL 4.5 Specification, Page 11](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf)*

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want!